# Access filesystem from AEM

Tags: aem

Is there a way to access a file (present on the File System) from AEM. More specifically, I have requirement wherein:
 1. I need to fetch a custom log file (present under crx-quickstart/logs/.log
 2. Send an email with this file attached via AEM

Any inputs would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via java fileinputstream and associated api's. Use relative paths to access the file so that once your code is deployed to other environments(servers) it doesn't error out with any IO exception.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is same as [Link to your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438632/attach-file-from-my-local-machine-to-send-mail-in-cq-aem/33808853#33808853)

This is just a suggestion that go for the question suggested by the stackoverflow first when you are typing your question. As the same question has already been asked before.

Thank you...

Comment: The link you posted was helpful.
My case is slightly different in that I don't have a form where the file is uploaded. 
I was able to meet the requirement using following:

EmailAttachment attachement = new EmailAttachment();              attachement.setPath(<cq install directory>/logs+"/"+<file name>);
               email.attach(attachement);